# Typesctipt quick way to check if array of object exist, and object exist, and object prop exist?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I have to do these checks before assing the value of object props:

```
if (Store != undefined) {
      if (Store.someItem != undefined) {
          if (Store.someItem['title'] != undefined) {
              title = Store.someItem['title']
          }
      }
    }
```

**Is there short way to do this ?**

For example: the last check we could do like this:

```
title = Store.someItem['title'] || ''
```

Is it possible to make all these checks in short ways. Or may be you could give advise about the whole concept and how to avoid this situation when I need to do these checks ?

Comment: what if store value is null or any other falsy value ?

Comment: You don't have to nest the `if` conditions. `if (Store && Store.someItem &&  Store.someItem.title) title = Store.someItem.title` Or, as mentioned in the duplicate, you can create a function to get the nested properties by using a try catch.